# Null child component value while executing onMounted (Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I can't see why component myComp.value is null when executing onMounted whereas this is working well by using script setup or when I access the child component with $ref:

FF: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: myComp.value is null

Edge: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'rand')

```
<template>
  <MyComp ref="myComp" />
  <h2>{{ myInt }}</h2>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import MyComp from "./MyComp.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MyComp,
  },
  setup() {
    const myComp = ref(null);
    const myInt = ref(0);

    onMounted(() => {
      myInt.value = myComp.value.rand();
    });

    return {
      myInt,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <h2>Component</h2>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup(_, context) {
    const rand = () => {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    };

    context.expose({ rand });

    return {
      rand,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Script setup (working well):

```
<template>
  <MyComp ref="myComp" />
  <h2>{{ myInt }}</h2>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import MyComp from "./MyComp.vue";

const myComp = ref(null);
const myInt = ref(0);

onMounted(() => {
  myInt.value = myComp.value.rand();
});
</script>
```

$ref (working well):

```
    onMounted(() => {
      let instance = getCurrentInstance();
      myInt.value = instance.ctx.$refs["myComp"].rand();
    });
```

Comment: Why do you call the method on the child component directly instead of using events?

Comment: I'm more trying to understand if it's expected to be null/why it's null

Comment: You didn't return `myComp` in the first snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working well when I return myComp